# Process builder in JAVA not working in Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, processbuilder

Process builder in JAVA not working in Mac OS X:

```
String[] command = { "mkdir", "one"};

ProcessBuilder process = new ProcessBuilder(command);

process.start();
```

after this "one" directory is not created in Mac 'Home' user directory.

Comment: how do you run your code? This snippet will create folder 'one' in folder,  where you jar runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the working directory in your process builder. Setting it to user's home in Mac, you can use the system property `user.home`:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
pb.directory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
pb.start();
```

According to the Javadoc for [`java.lang.ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html):

> Each process builder manages these process attributes:
>
> - ...
> - a *working directory*. The default value is the current working directory of the current process, usually the directory named by the system property `user.dir`.